# Due to, because of, on account of, because,

Tags: grammar

Forgive me, but I have read some of these explanations and I still cannot really understand the differences. I would like to be able to explain it to some English learners in a nice and clear way so that they understand it.  Because if I don't really understand it myself, how can I explain it well to someone who does not speak our language.
I really appreciate any help I can get here.

Comment: Which specific part didn't you understand? This question is too broad!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Due to** (we used to be taught) accompanies the verb *to be* and can be replaced by **caused by**.

> "His illness **was** due to smoking."
> "His illness **was** caused by smoking."

**Not** "He became ill due to smoking."

We say,

> "He became ill because he smoked"
>  "He became ill because of smoking."

and

> "He became ill on account of all the cigarettes he smoked."
>  "It's
> cold on account of the wind."

or

> "He became ill because of all the cigarettes he smoked."
>  "It's
> cold because of the wind."

and

> "The low temperatures **were** due to/caused by the wind."